# Web sockets subscription managements for a large dataset and every client subscribing to unique list?

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket, stomp

I am designing a price subscription service where users will login and will get real time updates on security prices they are entitled to see. My security subscription is around 500,000 securities. Each client(web) is entitled to see a different subset of real time price streams. 
I have a spring boot service running on the server side that is streaming real time prices. I am planning to write these prices to stomp websocket which clients(web application) can subscribe to. Since the the subscription list can change, I am not sure how to manage these subscriptions between clients and securities. Creating 500K rooms to broadcast individual updates does not sound good at all. Would appreciate any suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you tied to Spring Boot or are you open to other solutions like Butterfly Server .NET ?

By real-time price streams, how often are they actually updating? Every second? Every minute?

Comment: I am tied to spring boot and websockets solution. Real time prices means around2-3 updates per security per second for around totol universe of 500k securities (though this is max throughput and almost never be the case, around 100k actively produce data at any time.)